# Question about the use of cleveref's \Crefrangeformat

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, cleveref

I am trying to use the package `cleveref` to reference to a range of equations. I'd like to have the following result in the text:

> Eqs. (1)-(5)

I want to be able to define the format once, using the command `\Crefrangeformat`, so, at the beginning of my document I have the following two lines:

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
\Crefrangeformat{eq}{#3(#1)#4-#5(#2)#6}
```

and in the text I type:

```
Eqs. \Crefrange{eq:eq_first}{eq:eq_last}
```

I'd expect the results to be:

> Eqs. (1)-(5),

while instead I obtain:

> Eqs. Equations (1)–(5)

Now my question is: why does the word "Equations" appear despite the fact that I didn't include it in the format declaration? Is there something subtle I am missing here?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 13):

In `\Crefrangeformat` you have to refer to a valid counter, in your case `equation` and not `eq`.

Also, you can insert "eqs." inside it not to have to specify it every time.

Moreover, it is better to define `\crefrangeformat` and leave `\Crefrangeformat` undefined, so when you use `\crefrange` you get the non-capitalised version and when you use `\Crefrange` you get the capitalised version.

In other words, you can define it as follows

```
\crefrangeformat{equation}{eqs. #3(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}
```

so that the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefrangeformat{equation}{eqs. #3(#1)#4--#5(#2)#6}

\begin{document}
\Crefrange{eq:eq_first}{eq:eq_last} and \crefrange{eq:eq_first}{eq:eq_last}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:eq_first}
a=b.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:two}
b=c.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:three}
c=d.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:four}
d=e.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:eq_last}
e=f.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Answer (score 9):

@karlkoeller and @Jubobs have already answered your question. @Jubobs is exactly right that you shouldn't be typing the "eqs." manually, but leaving cleveref to do that for you. (If you have exceptions in your document where you need the labels without the text, use `\labelcref` et al.)

Also, you shouldn't be using `\Cref<x>` (note the capitalisation) except at the beginning of sentences. If you want capitalised names, use the `capitalise` package option. (`capitalize` is also accepted, for my American friends who seem to consistently mis-spell it ;-) `\Cref<x>` don't only capitalise the text, they also use the full name instead of an abbreviation, as you shouldn't abbreviate words at the beginning of sentences in written English.

However, if all you want to do is change the text and the label formats, and nothing more fancy, then you're much better off using the high-level format customisation commands:

```
\crefname{equation}{eq.}{eqs.}
\creflabelformat{equation}{#3\textup{(#1)}#4--#5\textup{(#2)}#6}
```

(In fact, the first of these is not needed, as it's already the default definition unless you're using the `noabbrev` package option. Note also the double dash "--" in the `\creflabelformat` definition: numerical ranges should be separated by an en-dash in written English, not a hyphen. The `\textup` ensures the labels are always set in upright font, which I'm told is the correct style.)

The reason to avoid using the low-level formatting commands like `\crefrangeformat` is that, unless you're very careful (see the manual), you'll break support for things like `babel` and automatic theorem naming. You should use the high-level commands wherever possible (`\crefname`, `\creflabelformat`, etc.). It's rare that you'll actually ever need the low-level commands (`\crefformat`, `\crefrangeformat`, etc.).

Answer (score 7):

Remember: it's always easier for people here to diagnose the problem if you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

### Hardcoding is evil

The beauty of `cleveref` is that it removes the need for hardcoding and it allows you to easily change cross-reference format at any stage. Imagine if you hardcoded `Eqs` everywhere in your input file, and then changed your mind as to how cross-references to equations should be typeset; say you'd know like to have

> Equations (1)-(5)

instead of

> Eqs. (1)-(5)

Well, that would require a lot of search & replace in your input file, which is tedious and error-prone. `cleveref` allows you to make a local change in the definition of a cross-reference format, which is then effected throughout the document. In conclusion: let `cleveref` do the job and don't hardcode anything.

### An explanation of what's going wrong

See the `cleveref` manual (subsubsection 7.1.2):

> The cross-reference *type* is usually the name of the counter for the environment (`equation`, `chapter`,`section`, etc.).

The cross-reference *type* of the `equation` environment is `equation`, not `eq`.
Therefore, `\Crefrangeformat{eq}{#3(#1)#4-#5(#2)#6}` has no impact on how cross-references to equations are typeset and, when `cleveref` encounters `\Crefrange{eq:eq_first}{eq:eq_last}`, the default format for a cross-reference to range of equations is still going to be used. That's why you get

> Eqs. Equations (1)-(5).

### What you should do

I refer you to the answers by Toby Cubitt (the author of the `cleveref` package) and karkoeller.